# Error when creating animation from graph in Octave

Tags: octave

I am trying to make an animation from a graph and save the result as GIF or video.

The graph and the animation work well in MATLAB but I cannot save it as GIF.

`imread` gives this error:

```
Magick: "gswin32c" "-q" "-dBATCH" "-dSAFER" "-dMaxBitmap=50000000" "- 
dNOPAUSE" "-sDEVICE=ppmraw" "-dTextAlphaBits=4" "-dG
raphicsAlphaBits=4" "-r72x72" "-dFirstPage=1" "-dLastPage=1" "- 
sOutputFile=C:\Users ...
```

I tried the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29493060/creating-animation-with-multiple-plots-octave-matlab), but that error pops up.

This is my code:

```
clear all;
clc;

for m = 1:10
  n = m.*100;

  x  = linspace(0,1500,1500);
  x2 = linspace(n,1000+n,500);

  y2 = [((20e-6.*n + 0.008).*(sin(pi/1000.*(x2-n))).^2) ];

  y1 = zeros(1,n);
  y3 = zeros(1,1000-n);
  y7 = [y1 y2 y3];
  y8 = y7 + 0;

  y1 = (sin(pi/150*x)).^2;
  y3 = exp((x/400)-5);

  y5 = (y1.*y3)+y8;

  plot( x,y5);
  drawnow;
  #pause(0.01);
endfor


im = imread ("animation.pdf", "Index", "all");
imwrite (im, "animation.gif", "DelayTime", .5);
```

EDIT:
This is the complete error. Directory name redacted for privacy.

```
    Magick: "gswin32c" "-q" "-dBATCH" "-dSAFER" "-dMaxBitmap=50000000" "-dNOPAUSE" "-sDEVICE=ppmraw"
"-dTextAlphaBits=4" "-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4" "-r72x72" "-dFirstPage=1" "-dLastPage=1" "-sOutputFil
e=C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" "--" "C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" "-c
" "quit" [No such file or directory].
error: Magick++ exception: Magick: Postscript delegate failed (F:\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\animation.pdf) reported by coders/pdf.c:434 (ReadPDFImage)
error: called from
    __imread__ at line 78 column 10
    imageIO at line 118 column 26
    imread at line 106 column 30
    test_animation2 at line 6 column 4
```

Comment: There is no error in your posted snippet and I'm pretty sure it's from `plot` and not `imread`. Please add MCVE

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the `print animation.pdf -append` step in your code above, but, other than that, I cannot reproduce your error. The code works fine and produces a .gif as expected on my machine.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou, where should I add `print animation.pdf -append` ?
I tried the code again, and yes, it reproduce the error that I attached in my post.

Comment: assuming you're trying to do what Carandraug did in the linked post, the whole point is that you append one pdf 'page' to this file at each iteration of your loop, so that by the end you have a pdf with exactly as many pages as the number of frames you'll want in your animation.gif. In your code above you forgot to do the 'appending' step (I mean, you never even generate an animation.pdf file to begin with, where do you expect to read it from in the first place?). If I place that line just above the `endfor` instruction, everything works as expected for me.

Comment: This has nothing to do with imagemagick though, so I doubt the error you're getting is related ... unless you've created some sort of mismatched animation.pdf from earlier and you're getting an error while trying to read it.

Comment: (also, since it's an "appending" operation, the usual warnings about ensuring you start with a fresh file apply, etc)

Comment: aah , I see. I tried to modified my code during troubleshooting but forgot to put that line back. I did not noticed it because there is animation.pdf file in the directory.

I tried to put that line back, still same error.
I also tried to copy paste code from `Carandraug` and have the same error.

Comment: so, the pdf file is generated with the same number of pages as the number of frames. but I have that error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

For me, the solution was to install or reinstall the [GhostScript program](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html).

This was the error message I received:

```
Magick: "gswin32c" "-q" "-dBATCH" "-dSAFER" "-dMaxBitmap=50000000" "-dNOPAUSE" "-sDEVICE=ppmraw"
"-dTextAlphaBits=4" "-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4" "-r72x72" "-dFirstPage=1" "-dLastPage=1" "-sOutputFil
e=C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\gmncleNd" "--" "C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\gmEh1Xv4" "
-c" "quit" [No such file or directory].
error: Magick++ exception: Magick: Postscript delegate failed (C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\TexML2.0\IN
entrada\in.pdf) reported by coders/pdf.c:434 (ReadPDFImage)
error: called from
    _imread_ at line 80 column 10
    imageIO at line 118 column 28
    imread at line 106 column 33
```